# Get IDs of Items to be Published from Sitecore Publishing Processor

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8

I am trying write a custom publishing processor in Sitecore so that I can log the exact date and time that any item is published.  The code I am using (which I adapted from Uli Welterbach's code [here](https://reasoncodeexample.com/2013/10/02/publishing-sitecore-media-and-data-source-items/)) does not throw an error but it does not seem to give me the IDs of the items that are actually getting published.  What am I doing wrong?

```
 public class PublicationProcessor : PublishProcessor
    {        

        public override void Process(PublishContext context)
        {
            Assert.ArgumentNotNull(context, "context");                        
            var cqs = context.Queue.ToList();            

            string connectionString = "Data Source=MyServer;initial catalog=AuditHistory; User ID=sa;Password=123456789;Integrated Security=false;";
            var query = @"INSERT INTO [dbo].[ItemHistory]
                               ([ItemID])
                         VALUES
                               (@ItemId)";

            using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {

                foreach (var itemId in GetPublishQueueItems(context.PublishOptions))
                {
                    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, cn))
                    {
                        // define parameters and their values
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@ItemId", SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier, 50).Value = itemId.ToGuid();

                        // open connection, execute INSERT, close connection
                        cn.Open();
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        cn.Close();
                    }
                }

            }

        }

        private IEnumerable<ID> GetPublishQueueItems(PublishOptions options)
        {
            if (options.Mode == PublishMode.Incremental)
                return PublishQueue.GetPublishQueue(options).Select(candidate => candidate.ItemId).ToArray();
            return PublishQueue.GetContentBranch(options).Select(candidate => candidate.ItemId).ToArray();
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the `publish:itemProcessing` pipeline. This is triggered when an item is being published. You will obtain the item id. I have a blog post where by I have make use of the `publish:itemProcessed`, which is triggered after an item has been published. The link is https://hishaamn.wordpress.com/2016/04/07/sitecore-incremental-publish-summary/

The implementation will be similar

**Code Sample**

```
public void OnItemProcessing(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
   var itemArgs = args as ItemProcessingEventArgs;

   if (itemArgs != null)
   {
       //Retrieve the current Item being published;

       var itemId = itemArgs.Context.ItemId;

       //Your code here;
   }
}
```

**Config**

For Sitecore 7.x, the `publish:itemProcessing` is found in the **Web.config** and for Sitecore 8.x, the `publish:itemProcessing` is found in the **Sitecore.config** from the App_Config folder
Thanks

Comment: That works.  Thanks!  However, when I run it the context.VersionToPublish is always null.  Do you know why that might be?

Comment: Great. The VersionToPublish is available after the item has been published. If you hook into the `publish:itemProcessed` the VersionToPublish will not be null

Answer (score 0):

You can try context.ProcessedItemIds